# Print a parameter from a def

Tags: python

### Here is the code I have. I am doing sample problems and added some code to it.

```
def RemoveChars(word, n):
    print("Original string: ", word, ".")
    x = word[n:]
    return x


print("Removing characters from a string")
print(RemoveChars("pynative", 4))
print("Removed the first ", n, "letters.")
print(RemoveChars("pynative", 2))
print("Removed the first ", n, "letters.")
```

---

The key thing that I am trying to fix is where it says `print("Removed the first ", n, "letters.")`, I am trying to retrieve the input parameter `n` and print it to say something like: "Removed the first 4 letters." or "Removed the first 2 letters." (a.k.a. - "Removed the first n letters.")

Comment: You can't retrieve it as it was a local variable in your function. Give it a name before and use it both in the function call and the print: `n = 4; RemoveChars('....', n); print('...', n, '...')`

Comment: why is `print("Removed the first ", 4, "letters.")` not possible ?

Comment: Maybe you even want to do this in a `for` loop? I'm unclear what you're ultimately getting at. If you're just debugging your code and inspecting what happens along the way, you could just put this second `print` inside the function (before the `return`).

Comment: As side notes: it's better for functions to return their output rather than print it. Also, you should have a look at [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/), the very well respected Python style guide. For example, Capitalized names are reserved for classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't retrieve n from a function, if it's not returning it. So best way would be to add print("Removing characters from a string") inside the RemoveChars function

```
def RemoveChars(word, n):
    print("Original string: ", word, ".")
    x =word[n:]
    print("Removing first",n,  "characters from a string")  
    return x
```

If you're familiar with format method(you can learn it quickly) in python you can do it even better:

```
def RemoveChars(word, n):
    x =word[n:] 
    return f"Original string was {word}, we removed {n} letters and now the string is: {x}"
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the returned value from a function you need to create a local variable to store it.

If there is more than one values returned then you would need more than one local variable to store it.

Hope the solution below could explain for you:

```
def RemoveChars(word, n):
    ''' Remove character of a string

    word parameter is the word
    n is a number 
    '''
    x = word[n:]
    return x,n

returned_x_n_4 = RemoveChars("pynative", 4)  # Calling for the function 
                                             # and passing positional arguments
                                             # and stored the returned value
                                             # in returned_x_n_4 aka function instance
returned_x_n_2 = RemoveChars("pynative", 2)  # Same operation but with different value

new_word_4, number_4 = returned_x_n_4  # Store each returned value into 2 different variable
new_word_2, number_2 = returned_x_n_2  

print("Original string: pynative.")
print("Removing characters from a string\n")
print("Removed the first ", number_4, "letters.")  # Print the number of letter removed
print("The new string is: ", new_word_4, end='\n\n') # Print the new string created

print("Removed the first ", number_2, "letters.")  # For a different value
print("The new string is: ", new_word_2, end='\n\n')
```

Or if you does not want to store it in a local variable, you could access the returned value trough index,[]. As below:

```
def RemoveChars(word, n):
    ''' Remove character of a string

    word parameter is the word
    n is a number 
    '''
    x = word[n:]
    return x,n

returned_x_n_4 = RemoveChars("pynative", 4)  # Calling for the function 
                                             # and passing positional arguments
                                             # and stored the returned value
                                             # in returned_x_n_4 aka function instance
returned_x_n_2 = RemoveChars("pynative", 2)  # Same operation but with different value

print("Original string: pynative.")
print("Removing characters from a string\n")
print("Removed the first ", returned_x_n_4[1], "letters.")  # Print the number of letter removed
print("The new string is: ", returned_x_n_4[0], end='\n\n') # Print the new string created

print("Removed the first ", returned_x_n_2[1], "letters.")  # For a different value
print("The new string is: ", returned_x_n_2[0], end='\n\n')
```

The output suppose to be like so:

```
Original string: pynative.
Removing characters from a string

Removed the first  4 letters.
The new string is:  tive

Removed the first  2 letters.
The new string is:  native
```

All the best!